# Benifits Of Using WPF to Develop Softwares

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

What Is Benefits of Using Wpf?

WPF Software Is Speed Or Windows Form or Not Different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few good reasons:

- It is the current recommended GUI framework for app development from Microsoft.  Using the recommended framework is good because you're sure they will be supporting it for some time and adding to it probably.
- WPF uses DirectX and hence the GPU instead of Winforms which uses GDI for everything.  Anything offloaded from the CPU helps.
- You can use a form designer plus edit easy to understand XML instead if you prefer.
- It is based on XAML just like Silverlight is, and so you can do web and app development without too much extra work.
- Creating custom controls are very easy
- You can easily bind to objects properties and collections right inside your XAML.

Comment: And debugging WPF is a challenging, brain-stimulating exercise.

Comment: IMHO those two points are a little weak. Apple wants cocoa, Sun wants swing (or whatever, i neither develop for Mac nor with Java), Microsoft WPF... It's no benefit if someone recommends something. And about DirectX and GPU: Most applications ran fine with Winforms and office PCs rarely have/had a need for a good graphics hardware, so why should they suddenly require more expensive hardware? There is rarely a case where an office program requires extensive graphics capabilities and most of the software out there _is_ office software. Anyways, i still agree that WPF is superior.

Comment: @dbemerlin: Added some depth into the answer for why those 2 points matter.

Comment: @dbemerlin: you're right that WPF is overkill for business apps, but I think the whole point of WPF is to expand the range of what's possible in Windows. Although to be fair, it's more like it expands the range of what's *easy to do* in Windows, because you could always do pretty much anything you wanted in Windows with a little work.

Comment: WPF is absolutely no overkill for business apps - the XAML / Code split is marvelous, and if you do ANY visualization, the performance is great. That said, I Have a funny focus mostly building high performance graphical visualizations recently (for financial data streams). But after some getting into, I find WPF a lot better to even program with than WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

- works great on windows
- easy to develop with visual studio
- modern framework
- data binding
- job opportunities
- "zammel" (XAML :))
- huge support from Microsoft
- MSDN libraries
  etc. etc.

Maybe you have another tool you feel comfortable with, so use it :-)
But if you are new, why not to learn this powerful framework?